# What is the maximum gas price that we can set in a transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, gas

what is the maximum gas price can we set it in a transaction ?

I am always using '3000000' to avoid 'run out of gas exception' (poa network)

But when I got `'replacement transaction underpriced'` I cant resolve it

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is ("the balance of your account" - "the value that you set in the transaction") / "the gas-limit that you set in the transaction".

Comment: so why I always get 'replacement transaction underpriced' ? I add gas

Comment: You have probably sent an earlier transaction with the same nonce and a higher price (and now you're trying to override it, but with a lower price, which is impossible).

Comment: actually I have 4 transactions in queue (and I dont know why they was not mined), and I can send any new transaction